# How can I make Ruby Gosu properly load a file path with variables to represent file paths?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, libgosu

Currently, I have this issue where I need to load the music files into ruby so that it can be played.
While it works with absolute path, it doesn't work when I use variables to represent the file path so that i don't have to manually type in the file path.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
def playTrack(track_name, album)
    track = album.tracks.find {|t|t.name == track_name}
    track_path= track.location.to_s
    music_path= File.expand_path(track_path, File.dirname(__FILE__))
    puts music_path
    if track
        @song = Gosu::Song.new(music_path.to_s)
        @song.play(false)
    end
end
```

These are the variables that I used to present the file paths:

```
track_path = sounds/01-Cracklin-rose.mp3
File.dirname(__FILE__) = c:/Users/ultra/OneDrive/Documents/schoolstuff/uni/sem 1/programming stuff/programming work/portfolio/Distinction Tasks/9.1.3D/musicplayer
DIR.pwd = c:/Users/ultra/OneDrive/Documents/schoolstuff/uni/sem 1/programming stuff/programming work
```

the music file's path: C:\Users\ultra\OneDrive\Documents\schoolstuff\uni\sem 1\programming stuff\programming work\portfolio\Distinction Tasks\9.1.3D\musicplayer\sounds\01-Cracklin-rose.mp3

I was expecting the song to play as normal, however, it returned the error:

```
   C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/gosu-1.4.5/lib/gosu/compat.rb:116:in `initialize': Could not parse audio file c:/Users/ultra/OneDrive/Documents/schoolstuff/uni/sem 1/programming stuff/programming work/portfolio/Distinction Tasks/9.1.3D/musicplayer/sounds/01-Cracklin-rose.mp3 (RuntimeError)
: Couldn't open c:/Users/ultra/OneDrive/Documents/schoolstuff/uni/sem 1/programming stuff/programming work/portfolio/Distinction T
    from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/gosu-1.4.5/lib/gosu/compat.rb:116:in `initialize'
    from c:/Users/ultra/OneDrive/Documents/schoolstuff/uni/sem 1/programming stuff/programming work/portfolio/Distinction Tasks/9.1.3D/musicplayer/gui_music_player.rb:164:in `new'
    from c:/Users/ultra/OneDrive/Documents/schoolstuff/uni/sem 1/programming stuff/programming work/portfolio/Distinction Tasks/9.1.3D/musicplayer/gui_music_player.rb:164:in `playTrack'
    from c:/Users/ultra/OneDrive/Documents/schoolstuff/uni/sem 1/programming stuff/programming work/portfolio/Distinction Tasks/9.1.3D/musicplayer/gui_music_player.rb:231:in `block in button_down'
    from c:/Users/ultra/OneDrive/Documents/schoolstuff/uni/sem 1/programming stuff/programming work/portfolio/Distinction Tasks/9.1.3D/musicplayer/gui_music_player.rb:223:in `each'
    from c:/Users/ultra/OneDrive/Documents/schoolstuff/uni/sem 1/programming stuff/programming work/portfolio/Distinction Tasks/9.1.3D/musicplayer/gui_music_player.rb:223:in `each_with_index'
    from c:/Users/ultra/OneDrive/Documents/schoolstuff/uni/sem 1/programming stuff/programming work/portfolio/Distinction Tasks/9.1.3D/musicplayer/gui_music_player.rb:223:in `button_down'
    from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/gosu-1.4.5/lib/gosu/patches.rb:64:in `tick'
    from c:/Users/ultra/OneDrive/Documents/schoolstuff/uni/sem 1/programming stuff/programming work/portfolio/Distinction Tasks/9.1.3D/musicplayer/gui_music_player.rb:241:in `<main>'
```

I tried using another variable to represent File.dirname(**FILE**), used DIR.pwd, used File?exist to debug (returns false for whatever reason even though the file path can be located and opened in browser), file path seems to be correct, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters exclusively. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: It says "Could not parse audio file" which means maybe it doesn't know how to handle that MP3, or it's not actually an MP3 like you think it is.

Comment: The file can be read if I used an absolute file path, but I dont want to use it. I created another ruby file to see it can run the audio file, which it has no problem doing so.